# When I upload .Net Core 2.1 project to plesk server I got file or directory not found

Tags: .net-core, upload, plesk, asp.net-core-2.1

After I install **.NET Core 1.x and 2.0** as components using **Plesk installer**,

And install **SDK** and **runtime** components like the image below:

[image]

**I still got (404 - File or directory not found):**

[image]

**Please help.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved after I publish the project from the visual studio to the server using FTP.